# How to get git tags with search keyword and sorting

Tags: git, nant

I am using git command in Nant script for get all previous tag list sorted with datetime and search with particular keyword.

```
<property name="commandlineGetList" value="tag -l --sort=taggerdate | grep "_${solution.name}"" />
```

As I found taggerdate is used for get sorted tags and grep is used for search through specific keyword.
Actually it is running in git bash but not in nant script. I'm using here dynamic search keyword. So can you help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
<property name="commandlineGetList" value="tag -l --sort=taggerdate *_${solution.name}"/>
```

This command uses for fetch all git tags list along with specific keyword search.